# Algoritmo para cálculo de rota mais rápida entre dois pontos em camadas cartesianas paralelas (3D)

Tags: algoritmo

Eu estou trabalhando em uma solução que envolve determinar a rota de menor esforço entre dois pontos de um prédio. (Imagine estudantes em seu primeiro dia de universidade, e que precisam saber onde fica e como chegar a uma dada sala de aula em um prédio, ou como ir da sala atual para a próxima aula.)

Basicamente eu tenho uma estrutura cartesiana onde cada andar está mapeado. Eu também tenho indicadores de pontos de acesso (portas, rampas para deficientes, escadarias) e os pontos onde estes pontos se conectam (Escadaria do Térreo se conecta com escadaria do 2º andar em X48 Y4, por exemplo), mais ou menos como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde **ciano** indica uma escadaria, e **azul-estranho** elevadores, entre outros marcadores não exibidos.

(Para os daltônicos, minhas sinceras desculpas e algumas informações adicionais: as escadarias estão localizadas na parte superior direita dos mapas; os elevadores, próximos ao centro.)

Eu comecei meu código baseado em uma variante do algoritmo de Dijkstra chamado [A-Estrela (A*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), que é basicamente o [problema do caminho mais curto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) com algumas otimizações. (Curiosidade: Vários jogos implementam variantes do A* para determinar a rota de personagens em um mapa.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A* é perfeito para determinar rotas em um mesmo andar, porém eu tenho que levar em consideração os vários andares, cada um com um layout diferente.

### Pergunta

Existe alguma maneira mais apropriada para solucionar este problema?

<sub>Ou, de forma mais clara (obrigado bfavaretto),</sub>

Dado o fator adicional de N andares, existe algum algoritmo que seja mais indicado do que o A*?

<sub>**Disclaimer:**</sub>
<sub>[Imagem isométrica original de DougIllustrations.com](http://dougillustration.com.au/uncategorized/office-building-floors-vector-isometric-16/).</sub>

Comment: até tentaria te ajudar ... mas para um daltônico esse esquema de cores não esta ajudando

Comment: Eu colocaria +2 nessa questão se pudesse.

Comment: @Otto desculpe! Adicionei um parágrafo especialmente pra você. =)

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu acho que um formato mais claro da pergunta seria "Dado o fator adicional de N andares, existe algum algoritmo que seja mais indicado do que o A*?" Um outro ponto é performance (N usuários calculando suas rotas ao mesmo tempo), mas eu não quero saturar a pergunta com outras 3984 associadas...

Comment: Ok, agora entendi. Me parece que você precisa de algo como um A*, só que em 3D. Como não é minha especialidade, deixo apenas um link que achei agora no Google: http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2011/09/24/another-faster-version-of-a-2d3d-in-c/

Comment: @bfavaretto Baixei e estou dando uma olhada. Eu procurei antes de postar, mas nunca me ocorreu procurar por A* e 3D. Mad Googlin' skillz, bro.

Comment: OnoSendai e @bfavaretto neste caso não é 3D, mas sim varios planos 2D interligados em pontos específicos. 3D seria se você estivesse de jetpack pelo prédio, e fosse se deslocar na vertical dentro do próprio andar (do ponto que está até o buraco na laje onde passa a escadaria, por exemplo).

Comment: Em que software foram feitas estas ilustrações dos andares?

Comment: @Tony Boa pergunta - eu apenas procurei por uma imagem que mostrasse os andares em formato isométrico, facilitando assim a visualização (keywords: isometric floors). Parece que o original é de um designer australiano - vou incluir o link para o trabalho dele no post.

Comment: @Otto [2], também sou (levemente de verde e vermelho). E realmente quando alguém vai fazer alguma coisa que envolva cores, existem tantas cores normais, e o cara coloca cor que não é padrão... Aí complica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A* é o que é normalmente usado, mas existe [uma família de algoritmos chamada D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*) que considera que o cálculo pode variar de etapa pra etapa, mas esse seria interessante se o caminho não fosse constante, como acredito que é o caso da sua realidade.

[Há ainda uma versão mais simples de ser implementada chamada D* Lite](http://pub1.willowgarage.com/~konolige/cs225b/dlite_tro05.pdf), que é bem diferente do D* original.

Comment: Na verdade D* pode ser uma boa opção se eu considerar que elevadores têm um 'custo' padrão menor do que escadas, mas que pode variar dependendo do horário - 'Vale a pena esperar pelo elevador na hora do almoço, ou é melhor descer dois lances de escadaria?' Mas esta é uma questão posterior.

Comment: Também. Na verdade você me fez desenterrar algum conhecimento das aulas de Teoria dos Grafos que tive há uns 8 anos atrás.

Comment: Eu encontrei uma implementação D*, vou dar uma olhada e ver como posso aplicar. Link - http://idm-lab.org/project-a.html

Comment: Update: Até o presente me parece que o D* Lite possui um custo melhor, já que não há a necessidade de recalcular o custo do caminho até alcançarmos um dos pontos de acesso.

Answer (score 11):

De uma forma bem simples, conectar os andares por uma aresta, criando uma espécie de grafo tridimensional me parece a solução mais adequada.

O algoritmo, no entanto, deve ser customizado conforme certas condições. Por exemplo, a configuração para deficientes iria colocar um custo infinito nas escadas e demais vias sem acessibilidade para que estas nunca fossem selecionadas.

A questão de evitar elevadores em horários de picos poderia ser outra configuração a cargo do usuário. Já uma opção de "andar no máximo `X` andares" seria um pouco mais trabalhosa, exigindo armazenar um estado adicional para cada rota.

E para a coisa funcionar bem na prática, seria ideal ter métricas de tempo média de espera dos elevadores em cada horário.

A ideia geral é que os pesos de cada aresta, isto é, de andar cada trecho, teria que baseado numa função dinâmica que considerasse as configurações do usuário e também informações de tráfego daquele trecho.

Porém, dependendo da quantidade de nós e da carga de uso do sistema, isto pode ser pouco eficiente. Neste caso, seria possível definir rotas subótimas, por exemplo, pré-calculando para cada andar a menor distância entre um determinado ponto e a escada ou elevador mais próximo, juntando então essa informação para selecionar uma global.

Enfim, essas são algumas ideias. Elas não respondem de forma conclusiva ou matemática a questão (e são grandes demais para comentários), mas espero que possam gerar novas ideias que incrementem sua solução atual.

Comment: Excelentes pontos, eu já incorporei alguns à lista de 'coisas que DEFINITIVAMENTE precisamos ter'. =)

Answer (score 9):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: Esta não é uma resposta *per se*, apenas uma compilação das respostas/possibilidades até o momento. Imagino que o resultado final venha a ser uma combinação das sugestões apresentadas.</sub>

### A* 3D (@bfavaretto)

Uma implementação possível deste algoritmo mapearia os pontos de contato entre os andares, implementado as 'lajes' como descrito por @bacco. A altura de cada camada pode ser definida como 1, já que não usaremos jetpacks, evitando assim o cálculo de custo horizontal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem, vermelho indicaria elevadores e azul, escadarias; verde, as paredes (objetos intransponíveis) e branco o espaço navegacional. (Espero que esta combinação de cores seja válida para daltônicos!)

### D* / D* Lite (@Cigano)

Esta é bem interessante por permitir cálculos de custo composto de tempo. Algumas situações possíveis:

- O ponto a ser alcançado é em um andar **superior**. O custo inicial de elevador é 10, +2 por andar. O custo de escadarias é 5 inicialmente, mas é adicionado 10 a cada andar a ser percorrido (+15, +25, etc.) Subir 1 andar pelas escadas pode ser melhor do que esperar pelo elevador, mas não é o caso se você precisar subir 10.
- O ponto a ser alcançado é em um andar **inferior**. Custo de elevador: 10 +2 por andar. Custo de escadarias: 5 +3 por andar (Não é tão cansativo descer uma escada, mas toma tempo.)

### Otimizações (@utluiz)

Várias sugestões boas aqui, algumas não relacionadas diretamente à pergunta porém podem ajudar a criar uma solução bem melhor.

- A informação sobre a presença de alguma deficiência física nos usuários cadastrados está presente, e a otimização de rota eliminando escadarias é possível. Uma configuração similar pode ser oferecida a usuários públicos via seleção na interface.
- É possível utilizar OpenCV para analizar ruído em imagens das câmeras que observam os elevadores, entradas e escadarias e traçar um histograma por horário. O resultado poderia ser um multiplicador de custo.
- Uma possibilidade de otimização deste algoritmo é definir zonas dentro de cada andar que possuem apenas uma possibilidade de rota de saída, e manter um cache com custos para pontos pré-determinados comuns (pontos de acesso, etc.) Isso pouparia um pouco do *workload*.

Comment: Acho que isso ficaria melhor na sua própria pergunta, pois se surgirem mais respostas, essa aqui via ficar perdida.

Comment: @Patrick Isso não iria contra a prerrogativa de 'não responder no corpo da pergunta'? Afinal, se não houver uma 'resposta definitiva', eu marcarei esta como resultado final - uma compilação de todos os pontos válidos mencionados pelos participantes.