# O que são os Algoritmos de Busca de Caminho?

Tags: algoritmo, inteligência-artificial

Nos estudos da faculdade, me deparei com os algoritmos de Busca de Caminho.

A parte teórica me confundiu bastante e eu estou limitado para entender os usos desse algoritmo na prática.

- O que são os Algoritmos de Busca de Caminho?
- Quais tipos existem?
- Quais os mais utilizados?
- Além do famoso Google no Google Maps, onde mais que esses algoritmos são utilizados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que são os Algoritmos de Busca de Caminho?

São algoritmos que se propõem a solucionar o [problema do caminho mínimo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caminho_m%C3%ADnimo).

> Quais tipos existem?

Do [artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caminho_m%C3%ADnimo):

- [Algoritmo de Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) — Resolve o problema com um vértice-fonte em
  grafos cujas arestas tenham peso maior ou igual a zero. Sem reduzir o
  desempenho, este algoritmo é capaz de determinar o caminho mínimo,
  partindo de um vértice de início v para todos os outros vértices do
  grafo.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- [Algoritmo de Bellman-Ford](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bellman-Ford) — Resolve o problema para grafos com um
  vértice-fonte e arestas que podem ter pesos negativos.
- [Algoritmo A*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_A*) — um algoritmo heurístico que calcula o caminho mínimo
  com um vértice-fonte. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- [Algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Floyd-Warshall) — Determina a distância entre todos os
  pares de vértices de um grafo.
- [Algoritmo de Johnson](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Johnson) — Determina a distância entre todos os pares de vértices de um grafo, pode ser mais veloz que o algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall em grafos esparsos.

> Quais os mais utilizados?

Jogos fazem bastante uso de implementações de [Dijkstra](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-implement-dijkstras-algorithm-pathfinding-c.146169/) e [A*](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/astar-path-finding-sample-150-lines-of-code.106892/).

> Além do famoso Google no Google Maps, onde mais que esses algoritmos são utilizados?

Como mencionados, jogos fazem bastante uso de algoritmos SPP (*Shortest path problem*).

Algumas [soluções de arquitetura e usabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32380/algoritmo-para-c%C3%A1lculo-de-rota-mais-r%C3%A1pida-entre-dois-pontos-em-camadas-cartesia) também fazem uso de algoritmos similares.

Answer (score 3):

### O que são?

Como próprio o nome já diz, são algoritmos que buscam encontrar o caminho de um ponto X até um ponto Y dentro de uma estrutura de dados, geralmente **grafos**.

### Quais tipos existem?

Existem os mais variados tipos, algoritmos para buscar [caminho mínimo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caminho_m%C3%ADnimo) entre dois pontos, o [caminho de custo máximo](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos_para_grafos/aulas/max-weight-paths.html), caminho mais rápido baseado no histórico...

### Quais os mais utilizados?

Não diria os mais utilizados, mas os mais famosos para determinar o caminho mínimo por exemplo, são:

- [Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra)
- [A*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_A*)
- [Bellman-Ford](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bellman-Ford)
- [Floyd-Warshall](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Floyd-Warshall)

### Onde mais são utilizados?

São constantemente utilizados em mapas como tu mesmo comentou, também estão presente em jogos, quando por exemplo o computador tem que simular caminhos dependendo do nível ou não, resumidamente esses algoritmos podem aparecer para resolver problemas de logística, redes de computadores e de telecomunicações, etc...

Answer (score 2):

### ***O que são os Algoritmos de Busca de Caminho?***

*- Tendo uma abordagem mais informal sobre o assunto, tirando toda a partida chata e teória que se aplica na faculdade quando estudamos a matéria sobre Teoria dos Grafos. os Algoritmos da Busca de caminho procuram um único ideal, o caminho mínimo. E para encontrar esse caminho mínimo você tera que seguir um conjunto de regras para cada tipo de algoritmo que foi definido de acordo com algum estudo(obra, teorema, qualquer coisa elaborada por um cara no passado, que foi amplamente aceita e testado).*

### **Quais tipos existem?**

(Respondendo aqui a parte dos mais utilizados também)

*São vários os tipos de algoritmos de busca de caminho mínimo, porém para efeitos de estudos devemos se ater aos principais algoritmos, que são os que caem em provas, concursos e etc, são eles:

> Wikipédia, um bom resumo sobre os principais utilizados.
>   - Algoritmo de Dijkstra  — Resolve o problema com um vértice-fonte em grafos cujas arestas tenham peso maior ou igual a zero. Sem reduzir o
>   desempenho, este algoritmo é capaz de determinar o caminho mínimo,
>   partindo de um vértice de início v para todos os outros vértices do
>   grafo.*
>
> - Algoritmo de Bellman-Ford  — Resolve o problema para grafos com um    vértice-fonte e arestas que podem ter pesos negativos.
> - Algoritmo A*  — um algoritmo heurístico que calcula o caminho mínimo    com um vértice-fonte.
> - Algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall  — Determina a distância entre todos os    pares de vértices de um grafo.
> - Algoritmo de Johnson  — Determina a distância entre todos os pares de    vértices de um grafo, pode ser mais veloz que o algoritmo de
>     Floyd-Warshall em grafos esparsos.*

### **Exemplos e onde são utilizados?**

Algoritmos de busca de caminho não se prendem apenas a exemplos de ligações sobre mapas, um exemplo que gosto bastante de citar é um sistema que foi feito utilizando várias conexões em pontos distintos para chegar a o destino final, uma "torre".
A idéia por trás onde os algoritmos de caminho mínimo são utilizadas é você ter a necessidade de chegar em determinado ponto com  a maior velocidade possível. Para resolver essa chegada, você vai aplicar algum dos algoritmos listados acima e verificar qual atende a sua necessidade, isso falando em termos de visão em algoritmos.

### **Observações:**

*A parte teórica desta disciplina é muito extensa, até me deparei com questionamentos do por que essa disciplina ter um embasamento teórico tão extenso, o jeito foi ler livros e livros na faculdade para conseguir a nota necessária. Procure algum livro é sempre bom, cursei a matéria a muito tempo e posso ter deixado passar algo importante.*

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversos tipos de algoritmos sendo os principais a busca do caminho mínimo. Um dos mais conhecidos é o de djikstra é usado em redes de roteamento de computadores. Muito comum seu uso em grafos com o problema do caixeiro viajante sendo um dos mais populares.